# Hide Superuser?

Tags: root-access, superuser

There are many apps out there that will hide your root su file and this seems to work well enough, but none of them are capable of hiding the Superuser application, not even 'Hide My Root' which claims it can do it but actually it doesn't do anything (Galaxy Nexus JB4.1.1., Superuser 3.1.1). Is there any way I could hide the Superuser app in such a manner that I could bring it back easily with an app rather than having to re-root my phone and re-mount/restore or just re-install the app itself?

My motives are not nefarious, actually I just want to get email on my phone but our 'Good' policy blocks rooted phones and once it sees Superuser it bails. This conflicts with the many tools I need available to me which require root access. I've tried putting Superuser into Ghost mode but this does little other than remove it from the launcher. I've tried SuperSU as an alternative to Superuser and Good still recognizes that. Maybe if there were some other lesser known Superuser app that might work but I haven't been able to find one yet.

Comment: SuperUser doesn't need root to be installed, and if you can hide `su` without removing it where does the problem arise?

Comment: The problem is I need to hide Superuser temporarily

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy way to hide root/Superuser temporarily. Just rename the Superuser app/apps to some other name in `/system/app`.

The disadvantage is that this will disable root for all apps.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to say that you were out of luck because I think Good actually checks for signs of being rooted, like an edited build.prop with usually unused arguments, odd system apps, root manager, any root access.

Again, I'm not 100% sure as I don't have any of it's source code.

But then I found [this](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.phantasm.xposed.gfesecuritypatcher)!!!

first you'll need to install [Xposed](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer)

after that disable Good

then install [this apk](http://dl-xda.xposed.info/modules/com.phantasm.xposed.gfesecuritypatcher_v26_ece4da.apk)

go into Xposed, enable the module installed above and reboot (to be sure it's active)

then re-enable Good, might not work as this module hasn't been updated, but worth a shot

Comment: Quite an old question asked in the days when Su detection mechanism are far inferior (no SafetyNet). Still it does count as valid...

Comment: I kinda want to down-to-earth this answer because it's just a set of links with no overview or information. ,

Comment: @AndyYan at least an answer a few years late is better than never

Comment: @acejavelin will add some info from my deleted answer